# Pre-loading text in textarea for user to edit and submit shows text briefly then blanks out. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I'm writing an edit function (plain javascript & HTML / Chrome / Windows 10).

The data is in localStorage as a series of records, just 2 records in the toy code mentioned below.

I want the user to specify the number of the record to edit, then the code should pre-fill the textarea field with the retrieved content of that record. I want to allow the user to make changes and then press a Store button to store it back in localStorage.

My problem is that when I prefill the input field, I see the record content briefly and then the input field clears.  I've tried .value and .defaultValue

`` editField.value = localStorage.getItem('jnl' + locStoreNo).replace(/(.*?)  `\d*?`/, "$1"); ``

and

`` editField.defaultValue = localStorage.getItem('jnl' + locStoreNo).replace(/(.*?)  `\d*?`/, "$1"); ``

the result is the same. (The regex is to hide a sequence number)

The code is in a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/roygrubb/zxedbfqr/2/

That performs more or less the same - it shows the value briefly - but then does something different: It goes to a 404.  I don't understand this either ¯_(ツ)_/¯

What I'm trying to do seems so basic, that I think I must be missing something blindingly obvious.

What have I missed?  Thanks!

Comment: Your `<button>` is submitting the form.  Make it `type=button` to prevent that.

Comment: That's it.  Thank you.  So I wasn't stupid, just plain ignorant!

Care to rephrase as an answer instead of just a comment so I can flag it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you've got a `<form>` that you want to handle through JavaScript, you have to ensure that the default form submission action does not happen. If the `<form>` does not have an "action" attribute, the default is to reload the current page.

By default, a `<button>` element will be assumed to have "submit" as its type. To prevent form submission, therefore, the simplest thing to do is make the button have "button" as its type.

That may not be all you need to do, depending on the details of the form. It may be necessary (or simply a good defensive move) to have a handler for the "submit" event on the form to prevent the default action.

Comment: Thanks for further enlightenment.